# How to Fix MISRA C++ Rule 0-1-4

Tags: c++, for-loop, misra

The following code violates the MISRA C++ rule 0-1-4:

```
for (auto &a : b) {
    ... // The variable a is used only in the for condition.
}
```

**Rule: A project shall not contain non-volatile POD variables having only one use. Variable 'a' is used only once, that is, during initialization.**

What I tried:

```
for (const auto &a : b) {
    ... // The variable a is used only in the for condition.
}
```

But that was not the solution.

Does anyone have an idea how I can fix it?

Comment: Is `a` actually used within the `for` loop?

Comment: No. See comment in code.

Comment: Perhaps request an exemption when a coding standard gets in the way? Tools should be working for you, not the other way around.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Do you think I should ignore this violation?

Comment: If your project rules allow you to choose which violation to ignore, then I'd say feel free to ignore it and suppress the message. Though if `(void)a;` trick works, feel free to use it too. I assumed it would violate some other rule.

Comment: The solution below does not violate any other rule. Thanks anyway for your tip. Since this MISRA rule is from the "**required**" category, you can't ignore it (as I understand it).

Comment: You can't use C++11 and MISRA C++ together, it's completely senseless. It's like having a corn flakes factory and placing one piece of nitroglycerine in each packet of corn flakes, then worry about if the nitroglycerine-placing machine is safe to use for the operator. Who cares, since you are, by design, counting on each of your products to explode in your customer's face?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alas the current C++ grammar requires you to declare a variable when using the range-for form of the `for` loop:

`for (auto& : b) {`

is not allowed, despite it having potential applications (such as computing the number of elements in a container).

Writing

```
a;
```

or

```
(void)a;
```

in the loop body might work depending on the type. This would fool the static analyser and you can hope the expression gets compiled out.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! :) That fixed it. But the new line violates another rule: "There shall be no dead code. Expression has no effect"

Comment: @KplnMoon: I've added another trick.

Comment: Wow! **(void)a;** does not cause any additional error and solves the problem. Thanks again!

Comment: @KplnMoon that is a verbose **shut-up** to the compiler.

Comment: @Red.Wave So you don't think it should be solved that way?

Comment: @KplnMoon it's normally used as a patch. You have not used the object, yet it has a name.

Comment: `#include <algorithm>` for c++20: `std::ranges::for_each(b,[&](auto const &/*a*/){/*a has no name*/});` or `std::for_each(begin(b),end(b),[&](auto const&){/*a has no name again*/});`

Comment: If there is a `break` then `find_if` works. `return true;` to `break` and `return false;` to `continue` with next element. These 2 library solutions are also imune to an alledged bug in range-based `for`.